# I checked this box: VMWare workstation console tools into system path. Now Chrome and Firefox don't work; it says proxy server is refusing connections

Tags: windows, vmware, proxy

I use Windows 10 Pro and I installed VMWare workstation 16.0.0 to use Ubuntu. I did an update for VMWare and I checked this box:

> VMWare workstation console tools into system path

Now, Google Chrome and Firefox don't work; it says something about the proxy server is refusing connections.

I would like to undo all the changes and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to disable the VM network adapter in

> Network and Sharing -> Adapter Settings

This should fix it. But if you plan to connect the VM machine instance to the Internet; this will not work. May be you should clarify the error by providing the error message. I hope this solves your problem regarding the browsers.